# How to download a Facebook post image using R?

Tags: r, facebook

I'm trying to download a post image or a post video into R so I can report the monthly performance of a Facebook page.

The fastest solution I could think of was to take a screenshot using `webshot`, but it is not what I need.

Has anyone tried to download a post image using the API with R?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `getPost ` from `Rfacebook` package?

Comment: Hi Vitali, no this doesn't bring the post image or video:
This is the description of the function.
getPost returns a list with up to four components: post, likes, comments, and reactions. post contains information about the post: author, creation date, id, counts of likes, comments, and shares, etc. likes is a data frame that contains names and Facebook IDs of all the users that liked the post. comments is a data frame with information about the comments to the post (author, message, creation time, id). 
Hope somebody have the answer!!!